# Arzela-Ascoli theorem on compact topological space

Tags: real-analysis

I read the theorem and its proof in Rudin's book and it was done for metric spaces. I have also read that the theorem holds in compact topological spaces. But the proof for metric spaces relies heavily on whether or not the space is separable (i.e. has a countable dense set). If the sequence $(f_n)$ is pointwise bounded, then given a countable set, a subsequence of it converges pointwise on that set. We take this countable set to be one which is dense in $X$. If $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous then the subsequence actually converges at each point. Then we prove that the convergence is uniform. Now I looked up and found various compact spaces that are not separable. So if we don't have separability how can we find such a pointwise convergent subsequence?

Comment: The following Wiipedia post has various version of the theorem and gives references: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem

Comment: See also p. 266 of Linear Operators Part I by Dunford and Schwatz.

Comment: I did read it before asking the question. The proof is done using previously proved results and not the way Rudin does it. The proof would be done if we had a pointwise convergent subsequence and I was wondering how to find it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But in Banach spaces $C(X)$ with $X$ compact (sup norm), sequentially compact is actually the same as compact.

Comment: Note that all compact metrisable spaces are separable, so that's why Rudin's proof works for that special case. Do you want to apply Arzela-Ascoli to non-metric $X$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes. I realize that a compact metric space is separable. I was wondering how it would apply if $X$ wasn't metrizable. If I could only show the existence of a pointwise convergent subsequence I would be done.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.